# Expected value of a die when decision to role again depends on previous outcome

Tags: probability, dice

> (Introduction to Probability, Blitzstein and Nwang)
>
> A fair die is rolled some number of times. You can choose whether to stop after 1, 2, or
>   3 rolls, and your decision can be based on the values that have appeared so far. You
>   receive the value shown on the last roll of the die, in dollars. What is your optimal
>   strategy (to maximize your expected winnings)? Find the expected winnings for this
>   strategy.

My solution:

My strategy would be to role again if the value is less or equal than $3$, because the expected value of the next die is $3.5$.

Let $X_i:=$ value of the $i^{th}$ role of the die, and $C_i:=X_i \leq3$. Then $P(C_i) = P(C_i^c) = \frac{1}{2}$ for $i=1,2$. Let $Y$ be the value of the final roll of the die.

\begin{align}
E(Y) &= \frac{1}{4} \left( E(Y|C_1,C_2) + E(Y|C_1,C_2^c) + E(Y|C_1^c,C_2) + E(Y|C_1^c,C_2^c) \right) \\
E(Y) &= \frac{1}{4} ( 2 +5 + 5 +5) = \frac{17}{4}
\end{align}

I would then think that in general for $n$ rolls of the die,

$$
E(Y) = \frac{1}{2^{n-1}}(2+5\cdot2^{n-1}),
$$

which goes to $5$ for large $n$.

Is this correct? Maybe somebody has a nicer approach to the problem.

**EDIT**

Based on the answers, I try to come up with an recursive solution

$$w_{j+1}=\sum_{k=4}^6 I_{(E(x)_j, 6]}(k)$$
$$ E(X)_{j+1}^* = \frac{1}{w_{j+1}} \sum_{k=4}^6 k \cdot I_{(E(x)_j, 6]}(k)$$
$$E(X)_{j+1} = \frac{w_{j+1}}{6} E(X)_{j+1}^* + \frac{6-w_{j+1}}{6} E(X)_{j}$$

Comment: @JohnD I think so, as it's independent of the previous one.

Comment: yes of course. For some reason I was doing 0-6, not 1-6. :-(

Comment: I don't get it. "your decision can be based on the values that have appeared so far". So I just wait and stop when I roll a 6?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Scenario $1$: You are allowed one die roll.  Your expected value is $3.5$.  Let us summarize this by saying $E_1=3.5$.

Scenario $2$: You are allowed up to two die rolls.  If your first roll is $3$ or less, you should reroll, since the expectation of your next roll is greater than $3$.  If your first roll is $4$ or greater, you should take that value, since if you roll again, your expected value is less than what you have.  So in this scenario, half the time you are taking $4, 5, 6$ (equally likely); and half the time you are taking $1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6$ (equally likely).  Thus your expected value here is $E_2=\frac{1}{2}5+\frac{1}{2}3.5=4.25$

Scenario $3$: You are allowed up to three die rolls.  If your first roll is greater than $4.25$ (the expected value if you pass on your first roll and go into scenario $2$), you should keep your first roll.  Otherwise you should go on and roll again.  $E_3=\frac13 5.5+\frac23 4.25=\frac{14}{3}$

Regarding long term behavior, I would think you should be able to approach an expected value of $6$, as the number of allowed die rolls increases.

Comment: Certainly as the number of allowed die rolls increases, the expected value tends to 6 because given enough rolls you will hit a 6 and then simply stop.

Comment: @JohnD: I agree (although it does depend on one's strategy).

Comment: I forgot that the decision rule might depend on the number of allowed tosses. I agree to your solution, but I don't understand where the weights in Scenario 3 come from.

Comment: @Dominik: If you roll a $5$ or $6$ on roll $1$ (probability $\frac13$), you keep it.  Otherwise (with probability $\frac23$) you go into scenario $2$.

Comment: @paw88789 Agreed, it is strategy-dependent. Some will risk walking away with \$1 in order to have a chance at \$6. More risk-averse people would be happy with simply beating the expected value.

Comment: That makes sense, thanks!

Comment: @JohnD. Yes, the winnings are strategy dependent. The question asks for the optimal strategy, which paw88789 identified.

Answer (score 0):

We can continue with paw88789's solution for arbitrary numbers of rolls.   To make the phrasing easier, I'll talk about the $n$th-to-last roll - what really matters here is how many rolls remain, not how many rolls you've already done.  We accept the $n$th-to-last roll if it's greater than $E_{n-1}$.

As paw established:

- you have to accept the last roll, and $E_1 = 7/2 = 3.5$.
- you should accept the second-to-last roll if it's at least 4, and $E_2 = 17/4 = 4.25$.
- you should accept the third-to-last roll if it's at least 5, and $E_3 = 14/3 = 4.66\ldots$.

We can continue with this scheme:

- accept the fourth-to-last roll if it's at least 5.  Then $E_4 = (1/3) (11/2) + (2/3) (14/3) = 89/18 = 4.94 \ldots$.
- accept the fifth-to-last roll if it's at least 5. Then $E_5 = (1/3) (11/2) + (2/3) (89/18) = 277/54 = 5.12 \ldots$.
  Now at this point, we accept the $k$th-to-last roll for $k \ge 6$ if, and only if, it's equal to 6.  (It's almost surely a coincidence that this works out to be 6.)  We get $E_k = (1/6) (6) + (5/6) E_{k-1}$, and it's not hard to expand this to get

$$ E_k = 6 - (47/54) \times (5/6)^{k-5} $$

for $k \ge 5$.  This approaches 6, of course, as $k \to \infty$.  The basic strategy for a very large number of die rolls (and this should hold up even with a different number of sides) is to hold out for the largest possible value for a long time, and only start accepting lower values in the last few rolls.